# Kotlin - async http calls

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous

I need to fetch data through 2 http calls. They are independent so they can be called in any order. Therefore I would like to run them asynchronously to save overall time needed for data fetching. What I did:

```
private fun loadDataAsync(param1: String,param2: String): HistoryData = runBlocking {
    return@runBlocking fetchDataAsync(param1, param2)
}

suspend fun fetchDataAsync(param1: String,param2: String): HistoryData = coroutineScope {
    var header: Header? = null
    var orderList: List<Order>? = null
    val job = launch {
        launch {
            header = headerClient.getHeader(param1) //it executes first http call
        }
        launch {                
            orderList = service.loadOrderList(param1, param2) //it executes second http call
        }
    }
    job.join()
    header?.let {
        return@coroutineScope HistoryData(
            header!!.name,
            header!!.group,
            header!!.price,
            orderList
        )
    } ?: HistoryData("", "", "", null)
}
```

The result is, they are always executed one by one and never together. What I am doing wrong ?

P.S.: maybe it is worth to mention, my app is spring boot web app, and this part of the code is called from controller.

Comment: Are `getHeader` and `loadOrderList` also suspend functions?

Comment: no, they are not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the solution which works for me

```
fun context() = Dispatchers.IO + CoroutineRequestContext() + CoroutineSecurityContext()

fun fetchDataAsync(param1: String,param2: String): HistoryData {
    val (header, orderList) = runBlocking(context()) {
      val headerAsync = async {
        headerClient.getHeader(param1)
      }
      val vehicleListAsync = async {
        service.loadOrderList(param1, param2)
      }

      Pair(headerAsync.await(), vehicleListAsync.await())
    }
    return HistoryData(
          header!!.name,
          header!!.group,
          header!!.price,
          orderList
      )
}
```

fun fetchDataAsync doesn't need to be suspend. Also methods headerClient.getHeader(param1) and service.loadOrderList(param1, param2) dont need to be suspend.

```
class CoroutineRequestContext(private val requestAttributes: RequestAttributes? = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()) : ThreadContextElement<RequestAttributes?>, AbstractCoroutineContextElement(Key) {
 companion object Key : CoroutineContext.Key<CoroutineRequestContext>

 override fun updateThreadContext(context: CoroutineContext): RequestAttributes? {
    val oldState = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()
    setCurrent(requestAttributes)
    return oldState
 }

 override fun restoreThreadContext(context: CoroutineContext, oldState: RequestAttributes?) {
    setCurrent(oldState)
}

 private fun setCurrent(requestAttributes: RequestAttributes?) {
    if (requestAttributes == null) {
        RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes()
    } else {
        RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(requestAttributes)
    }
 }
}

class CoroutineSecurityContext (
 private val securityContext: SecurityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()) : ThreadContextElement<SecurityContext?> {

 companion object Key : CoroutineContext.Key<CoroutineSecurityContext>

 override val key: CoroutineContext.Key<CoroutineSecurityContext> get() = Key

 override fun updateThreadContext(context: CoroutineContext): SecurityContext? {
    val previousSecurityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext)
    return previousSecurityContext.takeIf { it.authentication != null }
  }

 override fun restoreThreadContext(context: CoroutineContext, oldState: SecurityContext?) {
    if (oldState == null) {
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()
    } else {
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(oldState)
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `runBlocking`, which can make your coroutines run sequentially when the coroutines are blocking. You should instead use a proper coroutine scope with a threaded dispatcher like `Dispatchers.Default`, or `Dispatcher.IO` if your service-calls are using blocking IO.

Also, you should use async instead of launch to avoid mutating the `header` and `orderList` variables.

I would let the caller of `loadDataAsync` decide the coroutine scope. Everything considered, you would get something like this:

```kotlin
fun CoroutineScope.loadDataAsync(param1: String,param2: String): Deferred<HistoryData> = 
    async(Dispatchers.Default) { fetchDataAsync(param1, param2) }

suspend fun fetchDataAsync(param1: String, param2: String): HistoryData = coroutineScope {
    var header = async { headerClient.getHeader(param1) }
    var orderList = async { service.loadOrderList(param1, param2) }
    
    header.await()?.let { 
        HistoryData(it.name, it.group, it.price, orderList.await()) 
    } ?: HistoryData("", "", "", null)
}
```

Comment: Just want to add, if the structure of the program requires `loadDataAsync` to be blocking (maybe it's called by a class in another module and needs a synchronous result), then the sequential problem can be solved by adding a dispatcher, for example: `runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {`.

Comment: yes, loadDataAsync needs to be wrapped by runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO), otherwise I am not able to compile it. 
But now I am getting spring exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.